# Should a router reply neighbour solicitation?

Tags: ipv6

I found IPv6 routers in my college don't reply neighbour solicitation. At the first I think it's the bug of routers. To my surprise, I heard recently that my friends who are using Windows can use IPv6 network. It seems that Windows stores MAC addresses from router solicitation as permanent entries in neighbour table.

Must a router reply neighbour solicitation if it sends router advertisements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every device that has IPv6 must reply to neighbor solicitations for the addresses it has. Even routers.

Are you sure neighbor discovery isn't working? It might be that multicast filtering or unicast replies cause the packets to be invisible from your point of view.

Comment: I'm sure. Router solicitation is always replied. But neighbor solicitation is never replied. I'm just surprised at Windows behaviour.

Comment: @SherwoodWang: Yes, me too. I'll do some tests in my lab when I am back from my vacation...

Answer (score 0):

Router answer NS only when the source and destination are LLA (fe80::xxxx)

Comment: Welcome on the SuperUser! I think your answer is okay and correct, but it would be yet more better if you would give some reference or explanation.